# JSF: How to use selectOneRadio for immediate update of backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a choice of four locations, presented as a "selectOneRadio". When I select one location, the bean gets updated when I click to one of the commandLinks.

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{wrapper.goBack}" value="GESTERN"></h:commandLink>
    ---------
    <h:commandLink action="#{wrapper.goForward}" value="MORGEN"></h:commandLink>
    <br />
    <h:selectOneRadio id="locationSelection" value="#{wrapper.actualLocation}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{wrapper.allLocations}" var="actualLocation" ></f:selectItems>
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>    
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

What do I have to change when I want an immediate change of the backing bean when I click on a radio button?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the value property, instead set the value using a valueChangeListener method.

Comment: No, sorry, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: After re-read your question, I'm just asking why do you need to chage the value in the server when you're making changes in the client? It has no sense. What purpose it has? If you wanna do something in the client with the value of selected radio button, you should use JavaScript. If this is your scenario, I can post an answer handling the radio button value using pure JS. Also, please add the JSF version you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the submit at the time of click, you need to use Ajax.

For JSF 1.2, that means you need to use one of the many ajax frameworks for JSF (like richfaces with A4J).

For JSF 2.x, it's built-in.

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{wrapper.goBack}" value="GESTERN"></h:commandLink>
    ---------
    <h:commandLink action="#{wrapper.goForward}" value="MORGEN"></h:commandLink>
    <br />
    <h:selectOneRadio id="locationSelection" value="#{wrapper.actualLocation}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{wrapper.allLocations}" var="actualLocation" ></f:selectItems>
        <f:ajax event="click" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:form>    
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This will submit the form as soon as the radio button is clicked.
You can also specify which fields to process, and which to rerender.

See: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/

Comment: No, this also does not result in immediate feedback. When I reload the page, I get messages, that there are unhandled messages. Clicking on the radio buttons show no immediate results.

Comment: if you get unhandled messages, that means there's an error somewhere.  The annoying thing is that it does not actually show the messages, and sometimes it's difficult to get them to show. What I do (in 1.2) is to put a breakpoint on FacesContextImpl.addFacesMessage.  That way you can usually see where they're coming from.